# Spearman Correlation on top X% of sorted data

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I am trying to assess regression models not using the entire test set but only X% of top-ranked predictions, which is where the target of regression will be.
Is there any package in R that allows to do that?

So, for instance, if I have the following

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,8,7,9,12,11,14,15,16,17,20,25,40)
y<-c(0,1,2,4,5,6,8,7,10,12,15,14,13,10,18,22,30)
df<-cbind(x,y)
model<-lm(y~x)
summary(model)
```

Multiple R-squared:  0.9432,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9395

```
plot(y~x,df)
abline(model)
```

I would like to have a parameter "X"(30%) which is calculated not all entire dataset but only on top 30% data using Spearman's rank-order correlation index.
In this case it should be calculated only `x=c(15,16,17,20,25,40)`.
This "partial" correlation index could help in further characterization of models which might have poorer R-squared, but performing way better in precise region of the domain (e.g. Top X% of x).
Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: not entirely clear what you want: something like `lm(y~x,data=df,subset=x>quantile(x,0.7))` ?

Comment: @Ben. Thx. I do not want to alter the model with less data, just "measure" the model on a subset of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare predicted and actual values just for the relevant part of the data set, i.e.,

```
y.pred <- predict(model)
y.err <- y-y.pred
idx.part <- x > quantile(0.7)

# R squared
r.squared <- 1- var(y.err)/var(y)
r.squared.part <- 1- var(y.err[idx.part])/var(y[idx.part])
```

Not sure how to properly adjust R squared when computed on a subset. For the full data set, the [adjusted R squared is computed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48703/what-is-the-adjusted-r-squared-formula-in-lm-in-r-and-how-should-it-be-interpret) by multiplying the fraction term by `(n-1)/(n-p-1)`, where `n` is sample size and `p` is the number of predictors (1 in this case).

Comment: thanks for quick answer! I suspected there was nothing around in a package. And I am not sure either, on how to produce adjusted R squared. However, I keep on thinking that there are situations where regression models optimized on rankings of top x% predictions (i.e. maximizing Spearman's correlation on top or lowest X% data) could be preferred to "classical" models optimized on entire set.